# What is the difference between unlink and rm?

Tags: linux, shell

Is unlink any faster than rm?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." -- Donald Knuth http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Both are a wrapper to the same fundamental function which is an `unlink()` system call.

To weigh up the differences between the userland utilies.

`rm(1)`:

- More options.
- More feedback.
- Sanity checking.
- A bit slower for single calls as a result of the above.
- Can be called with multiple arguments at the same time.

`unlink(1)`:

- Less sanity checking.
- Unable to delete directories.
- Unable to recurse.
- Can only take one argument at a time.
- Marginally leaner for single calls due to it's simplicity.
- Slower when compared with giving `rm(1)` multiple arguments.

You could demonstrate the difference with:

```
$ touch $(seq 1 100)
$ unlink $(seq 1 100)
unlink: extra operand `2'

$ touch $(seq 1 100)
$ time rm $(seq 1 100)

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s

$ touch $(seq 1 100)
$ time for i in $(seq 1 100); do rm $i; done

real    0m0.207s
user    0m0.044s
sys     0m0.112s

$ touch $(seq 1 100)
$ time for i in $(seq 1 100); do unlink $i; done

real    0m0.167s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.120s
```

If however we're talking about an unadulterated call to the system `unlink(2)` function, which I now realise is probably not what you're accounting for.

You can perform a system `unlink()` on directories and files alike. But if the directory is a parent to other directories and files, then the link to that parent would be removed, but the children would be left dangling. Which is less than ideal.

**Edit:**

Sorry, clarified the difference between `unlink(1)` and `unlink(2)`. Semantics are still going to differ between platform.

Comment: Does that mean that in unix filesystems removing a directory and recursively all files under it will always be an operation that is proportional to number of files/dirs it contains? 

When happens when I unlink a directory that is parent to other dirs/files? It never gets wiped out and I lost this space forever?

Comment: It is technically possible leave orphaned directories/files on most if not all file systems.  Fixing this generally means running a file system repair tool.  On Unix/Linux these tools are known as 'fsck' and some specific variations for different file systems.  If they do recover something they will normally leave it in a directory called 'lost+found'

Comment: Correct. rm will recurse from the bottom of the tree up. You can demonstrate how with: `mkdir -p 1/2/3; touch 1/one 1/2/two 1/2/3/three; rm -ri 1`. If you unlinked the parent directory then space consumed by the children should be lost until such time that fsck finds the discrepancy.

Comment: What are you talking about?

$ mkdir -p 1/2/3
$ unlink 1
unlink: cannot unlink `1': Is a directory

Users causing "memory" leak requiring fsck? Unlikely!

Comment: Both Linux and FreeBSD manpages explicitly state that it will fail when trying to run unlink() on a directory.

Comment: I guess it depends on your implementation of `unlink(1)`. `unlink(2)` will certainly not care.

Comment: Dan C: what are you talking about? This is complete jibberish! Have you even tested what you're saying? $ strace -e unlink unlink 1
unlink("1")                             = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
unlink: cannot unlink `1': Is a directory

Comment: I've tested it on FreeBSD and Linux (ext2 and XFS)

Comment: Also, I was referring to the manpages of unlink(2). Of course they care!

Comment: Turns out Solaris with UFS does allow root to unlink non-empty directories. Not normal users though. Is there anything else that does? Not ZFS on Solaris, not anything on Linux or FreeBSD.

Comment: Is that with userland or system unlink()? That was the difference I was attempting to make.

Answer (score 11):

At the POSIX spec level, what [rm](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/rm.html) does is specified much more tightly than what [unlink](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/unlink.html) does.

The portability of the outcome seems likely to be better using rm, if your script has to run across OS's.

Answer (score 6):

The slow part of removing is the filesystem code and disk stuff, not the userspace preparation of the unlink() system call.

I.e.: if the speed difference matters, then you shouldn't be storing the data on the file system.

unlink is just a rm "light". rm has more features but they do the same thing.