# a2ensite equivalent in CentOS

Tags: centos

I already setup a **conf** for a site in the `/etc/httpd/sites-available`. However, I am wondering how can I enable this, like `a2ensite` in Debian, wherein the **conf** file will appear in the `sites-enabled?`

Comment: Use `vhosts.d` directory instead. `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` is a Debian-only thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mimicking the Debian config system isn't difficult.

1. In your Apache config, you have to include every `*.conf` file in
   `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled` with the directive `Include sites-enabled/*.conf`.
2. Add the config to a `*.conf` file in `/etc/httpd/sites-available`.
3. Activate the site in the config file by creating a link from the relevant file in
   `/etc/httpd/sites-available` into `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled`, which
   is basically the only thing that `a2enable` does on Debian.

Comment: I did `ln -s` but when I restart it failed to start the httpd.

Comment: Please add the failure messages (and your current config, if possible) to your question.

Comment: To clarify a bit, you need to edit your httpd.conf the directive to include the files in /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/. I have specified only the ones with a .conf extension using the following directive "Include sites-enabled/*.conf". You could also script a script to create and break the the link.

Answer (score 1):

Activate:

```
ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/mysite.com /etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.com
```

Deactivate:

```
unlink /etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.com
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, perhaps because it doesn't include the step to actually bring those files into the config? What is here is accurate though.

Also, unlink and rm are fundamentally the same. I avoid unlink as I've not come up with a scenario where it is better aside from an extremely small potential performance improvement. Details: http://serverfault.com/questions/38816/what-is-the-difference-between-unlink-and-rm